# Entity Framework DbContext - foreign keys and properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two tables in a SQL database with corresponding EF models coded like so...

```
public class ServicedPrinter
{
    [Key]
    public int printerID { get; set; }

    public int printerMakeID { get; set; }
    public int printerModelID { get; set; }
    public int printerDeptID { get; set; }
    public int printerSupplierID { get; set; }
    public string printerEQ { get; set; }
    public string printerURL { get; set; }
    public bool printerIsActive { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ServicedPrinter.printerSupplierID))]
    public virtual PrinterSupplier Supplier { get; set; }
}

public class PrinterSupplier
{
    [Key]
    public int supplierID { get; set; }

    public string supplierName { get; set; }
    public string supplierNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ServicedPrinter> Printers { get; set; } = new List<ServicedPrinter>();
}
```

I am trying to get the properties from the foreign table (`PrinterSupplier`) to join or display on the `ServicedPrinters` table.

Everything is fine up to this point until I view the data, the Supplier column displays as

```
'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ServicedPrinter_1E82E4C7936D795A0B752197D92132869A848F2B820F25074875C8F89A532E18'
```

Looking for any insight on how to properly join tables with Entity
Framework.

Thanks

At this point I've double checked that the foreign keys exist in the database. I've tried to map them manually. I've tried declaring the foreign properties. Nothing seems to work and I am either presented with an error regarding invalid columns or the data for the 'Supplier' column is displaying the type String

Comment: Dare say you didn't get EF to scaffold that DB for you then, looking at the casing of the property names? Does the database have relationships between the tables? Long story short you don't join tables with EF; you tell EF the relationship between the objects and then you just access them like you would any other set of C# objects where one has-a [collection of] other. EF will do the joins necessary to use the related data when it sees you using it e.g. `context.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Author == "Fred")`, (one Blog has many Posts, one Post has one Blog)

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code that you are trying to get the data from joining the tables. Besides that, looks like you are receiving an `proxy` that EF generate when you are trying to get some data. In that case you can try to parse this proxy to your real class, or you can use the `context.Tables.Find(id)`. But really? I prefer to use `context.Entity.Include(relatedEntity => relatedEntity.entityId).Where(entity => entity.Id == id)` to get the entity with the navigation filled and then use the data from navigation. I guess that is most common when the relation is not so complex.

Comment: It turns out that when I declare the navigational property 'Supplier', I am able to literally navigate the properties of the relational object by specifying the property. In my case i was looking to include the supplierPhone column which could be access by looking for 'Supplier.supplierPhone' field in the data.